# Let A be an m x n matrix whose rows are linearly independent. Prove that there exists a vector p such that Ap = e_1, where e_1 = (1 0 0 ... 0)^T

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I am studying linear and nonlinear optimization using the book by Griva.  The following is a question from one of the chapters and I am having difficulty formulaating a proof.  If anyone could give a quick one that would be great.  It isn't for a class, this is just for some self study.

Question:

---

Let A be an m x n matrix whose rows are linearly independent.  Prove that there exists a vector p such that $Ap = e_1$, where $e_1 = (1, 0, 0, ... ,0)^T.$

For the sake of simplicity you can assume that m < n, as that is the context that the book is working in.

---

Comment: In fact, $m\le n$ is a requirement, otherwise the rows of $A$ can’t be linearly independent in the first place. Hints: What is the rank of $A$? What does this say about its column space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If the rows of $A$ are linearly independent, what does that say about the row rank of $A$ (dimension of the row space of $A$)?
- The row rank of $A$ is the same as the column rank of $A$ (dimension of the column space of $A$). Note also that the column space is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$.
- "There exists a vector $p$ such that $Ap=e_1$" is equivalent to "$e_1$ is in the column space of $A$."